# What is macOS Sonoma? Does it exist?

Tags: macos, beta

While reading [an article](https://9to5mac.com/2022/02/15/system-preferences-mac-redesign-settings/) about System Preferences in macOS Ventura, I came across this image:
[image]

As you can see, it says "macOS Sonoma". Is this an existing macOS? Is it simply the name of the Ventura Developer Beta as of now? I don't have an existing device that I feel comfortable downloading the Beta on myself to check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the article

> A new concept imagines how Apple could revamp the System Preferences app design, with a focus on striking a balance between maintaining familiarity with the classic System Preferences design while also bringing it more in line with Settings on iOS and iPadOS.

This, together with the fact that the article was posted months before the WWDC, shows that it doesn’t describe an actual idea but rather an idea somebody had about how a revamped System Preferences panel could look like.

- https://basicappleguy.com/basicappleblog/settingsapp

They predicted a lot of things quite well but obviously their made-up name for the next macOS release missed the mark.

Comment: Ohhhhh, that makes sense... I suppose I should read more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

#### 2023 Update:

Apple announced macOS Sonoma in WWDC23.

The image in the question is a concept made before macOS Sonoma was announced.

Answer (score -2):

Apple has recently announced macOS Sonoma. You can directly download [macOS Sonoma DMG](https://techrechard.com/download-macos-sonoma-dmg-file/) and install it on your MAC.

What you saw above was most probably a conceptual image.

Comment: This is basically the same as [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460682/100490)